# Is there a way to get the state of pressed keys at runtime? without using event

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to get the **state** of pressed keys at **runtime**?

**without using events** like: '**keyDown**' or '**keyUp**' or '**keyPress**'.

Because this feature is supposed to be used in a basic class, I guess it will affect the performance.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance impact of using these events, you can consider implementing some optimization techniques to minimize the overhead. For example, you could use event delegation to handle key events at a higher level in the DOM tree, rather than attaching an event listener to each individual element. You could also use a debouncing or throttling technique to limit the frequency of the event handlers being called.

Comment: @Sachin Now that I think about it, I come to the conclusion that it is better to put this event on the main page and use it from there.
Thankful.

Comment: Another option is to use a library or framework that provides key event handling functionality, such as `keymaster` or `mousetrap`. These libraries can help to simplify the process of handling key events and can provide additional features and optimization options.